# List view not sending exact list item clicked

Tags: java, android, listview

Im not sure but my List is not working, supposed to be, when the onItemClick is hit, I should transfer that to a different class and open that activity, it is opening when i try to startactivity but not getting the exact item clicked to play. This is a media player btw. I really need help.

NowPlayingActivity

```
private ImageButton btnPlay;
private ImageButton btnForward;
private ImageButton btnBackward;
private ImageButton btnNext;
private ImageButton btnPrevious;
private ImageButton btnRepeat;
private ImageButton btnShuffle;
private SeekBar songProgressBar;
private TextView songTitleLabel;
private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
// Media Player
private  MediaPlayer mp;
// Handler to update UI timer, progress bar etc,.
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
private SongsManager songManager;
private Utilities utils;
private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int currentSongIndex = 0;
private boolean isShuffle = false;
private boolean isRepeat = false;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);

    // All player buttons
    btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
    btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
    btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
    btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
    songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
    songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
    songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
    songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);

    // Mediaplayer
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    songManager = new SongsManager();
    utils = new Utilities();

    // Listeners
    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important

    // Getting all songs list
    songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

    // By default play first song
    playSong(0);

    /**
     * Play button click event
     * plays a song and changes button to pause image
     * pauses a song and changes button to play image
     * */
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check for already playing
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                if(mp!=null){
                    mp.pause();
                    // Changing button image to play button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                }
            }else{
                // Resume song
                if(mp!=null){
                    mp.start();
                    // Changing button image to pause button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                }
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Forward button click event
     * Forwards song specified seconds
     * */
    btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // get current song position
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
            if(currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()){
                // forward song
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
            }else{
                // forward to end position
                mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Backward button click event
     * Backward song to specified seconds
     * */
    btnBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // get current song position
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
            if(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0){
                // forward song
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
            }else{
                // backward to starting position
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Next button click event
     * Plays next song by taking currentSongIndex + 1
     * */
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check if next song is there or not
            if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            }else{
                // play first song
                playSong(0);
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Back button click event
     * Plays previous song by currentSongIndex - 1
     * */
    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(currentSongIndex > 0){
                playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
            }else{
                // play last song
                playSong(songsList.size() - 1);
                currentSongIndex = songsList.size() - 1;
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Button Click event for Repeat button
     * Enables repeat flag to true
     * */
    btnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(isRepeat){
                isRepeat = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.repeat);
            }else{
                // make repeat to true
                isRepeat = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // make shuffle to false
                isShuffle = false;
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.repeat1);
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.shuffle);
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button Click event for Shuffle button
     * Enables shuffle flag to true
     * */
    btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(isShuffle){
                isShuffle = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.shuffle);
            }else{
                // make repeat to true
                isShuffle= true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // make shuffle to false
                isRepeat = false;
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.shuffle1);
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.repeat);
            }
        }
    });



}

/**
 * Receiving song index from playlist view
 * and play the song
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                 int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 100){
         currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
         // play selected song
         playSong(currentSongIndex);

    }

}

/**
 * Function to play a song
 * @param songIndex - index of song
 * */
public void  playSong(int songIndex){
    // Play song
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        // Displaying Song title
        String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

        // Changing Button Image to pause image
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

        // set Progress bar values
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);

        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Update timer on seekbar
 * */
public void updateProgressBar() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
}   

/**
 * Background Runnable thread
 * */
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
           long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

           // Displaying Total Duration time
           songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
           // Displaying time completed playing
           songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

           // Updating progress bar
           int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
           //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
           songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

           // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
           mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
       }
    };

/**
 *
 * */
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

}

/**
 * When user starts moving the progress handler
 * */
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}

/**
 * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
 * */
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

    // forward or backward to certain seconds
    mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

    // update timer progress again
    updateProgressBar();
}

/**
 * On Song Playing completed
 * if repeat is ON play same song again
 * if shuffle is ON play random song
 * */
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

    // check for repeat is ON or OFF
    if(isRepeat){
        // repeat is on play same song again
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else if(isShuffle){
        // shuffle is on - play a random song
        Random rand = new Random();
        currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else{
        // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
        if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
            playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
            currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
        }else{
            // play first song
            playSong(0);
            currentSongIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}

@Override
 public void onDestroy(){
 super.onDestroy();
    mp.release();
 }
```

TabSongsActivity (the list view)

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
        // get all songs from sdcard
        this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

        // looping through playlist
        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsListData.add(song);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
            R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.songTitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();
        // listening to single listitem click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                // getting listitem index
                int songIndex = position;

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    NowPlayingActivity.class);
                // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
                in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
                setResult(100, in);
                 startActivityForResult(i, 100);

            }
        });

    }
```

songsmanager

```
public class SongsManager {
    // SDCard Path
    final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/";
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private String mp3Pattern = ".mp3";
    // Constructor
    public SongsManager(){

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
        System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
            File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
            File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }
    private void scanDirectory(File directory) {
        if (directory != null) {
            File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void addSongToList(File song) {
        if (song.getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern)) {
            HashMap<String, String> songMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            songMap.put("songTitle",
                    song.getName().substring(0, (song.getName().length() - 4)));
            songMap.put("songPath", song.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(songMap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't see anything obvious here. maybe in SongsManager.getPlaylist?

Comment: I included songs manager njzk2, thanks for the reply! but i want to point out onItemClick on tabsongs activity, and onActivityResult on nowplayingactivity. Are they connected? Im not really sure because as a beginner, I just used reference from other sites and came up with these. I'll really be grateful if you can help me.

Comment: possibly scanning the filesystem does not yield the same result when called twice. you should at least make sure you only scan once.

Comment: I think you need to learn more about the basics of activities to be able to fix your problem. Read the documentation to see how it works and it'll be much easier to understand what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
int index = data.getIntExtra("songIndex", 0);
```

Instead of

```
int index = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
```

The method `getExtras()` returns a bundle set by using `putExtras()`.

EDIT:

In TabSongsActivity you have

```
   Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
        NowPlayingActivity.class);
    // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
    in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
    setResult(100, in);                  /// REMOVE THIS!!
    startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

In NowPlayingActivity, remove the onActivityResult, and put this somewhere else (maybe onCreate)

```
 Intent in = getIntent();
 int songIndex = in.getIntExtra("songIndex",0)
```

Comment: I'm having an error, The method getIntExtra(String, int) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: Oh, that's because that method takes two arguments. I updated answer. Second argument is default value in case the requested integer is not found.

Comment: Same output happened, maybe the error is from onitemClick or onActivity result? Can you please check?

Comment: Is your TabSongsActivity calling NowPlayingActivity? or is the other way around?

Comment: Yes, My TabSongsActivity is calling NowPlayingActivity. TabSongsActivity is the list of songs, NowPlayingActivity is the player that receives the OnItemClick from TabSongs.

Comment: If that's the case then everything is wrong. Your onActivityResult is probably never called!

Comment: Can you help me with this? I already tried transferring those codes but I have no luck.

Comment: I did that, but nothing is starting my activity, should I remove startActivityForResult(i, 100); too? I tried not to but It didn't work as well, I put  Intent in = getIntent();
 int songIndex = in.getIntExtra("songIndex",0) oncreate

Answer (score 0):

First, don't scan the sd card yourself. There can be hundreds of thousands of files on the sd card, and storing them all and then filtering down the list will likely be slow and/or run out of memory. Use the media content provider instead. It has already scanned the sd card for you, and can give you a list of just the music files on there, including artist/album/title and other metadata.

In your code, you are keeping two different copies of your song list: one in NowPlayingActivity, the other in TabSongsActivity, and you are populating them separately, scanning the sd card for each one. If anything changed on the sd card between those two scans, then the two lists will be different, and item N in one list may no longer correspond to item N in the other list. Use only one list.

Finally, the reason your code isn't working is because you are mixing up your startActivityForResult(), setResult() and onActivityResult().
The startActivityForResult should be in the activity that has the onActivityResult() method, while the setResult() call should be in the activity started by startActivityForResult.

As currently written above, you are simply launching NowPlayingActivity from TabSongsActivity. If that's really what you want, then you should just use plain startActivity(), and retrieve the intent and its extras in NowPlayingActivity.onCreate() or onResume or something. The onActivityResult method you implemented will never be called.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but before, this is working. The NowPlaying activity which is the player is formerly in a TabActivity so it is created at the start of mainActivity. And the TabSongsActivity is formerly an activity for a button which will open a list for that player. it worked fine, but now I realized that the list should be on the tab, so I switched the two activities. Added startactivity on  onItemClick but doesnt get the specific Item clicked now. Im very confused.

Comment: marcone is right here, you should also consider changing this.

Comment: You are mixing up your startActivityForResult() and setResult() calls.

Comment: Thank you very much marcone and Merlevede, I'll try to study it further. I'll present this the next day so I'm on a rush :) But thanks again for giving me leads!